# Installing time package on ubuntu will return a node-gyp error

Tags: node.js, npm, time

I am trying to start a project which includes the `time@^0.12.0` package so when I try to install it I receive the following error.

```
time.target.mk:113: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/time/src/time.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/time/src/time.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-1065-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time
gyp ERR! node -v v14.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! time@0.12.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the time@0.12.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

If I will try to use `--ignore-scripts` everything is fine up to the point where I start the project and get the following

```
/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:135
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/build/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/build/Debug/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/build/Release/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/out/Debug/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/Debug/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/out/Release/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/Release/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/build/default/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/compiled/14.3.0/linux/x64/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/addon-build/release/install-root/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/addon-build/debug/install-root/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/addon-build/default/install-root/time.node
 → /home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/time.node
    at bindings (/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:126:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/index.js:8:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/development/libraries/client/account.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30) {
  tries: [
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/build/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/build/Debug/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/build/Release/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/out/Debug/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/Debug/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/out/Release/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/Release/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/build/default/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/compiled/14.3.0/linux/x64/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/addon-build/release/install-root/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/addon-build/debug/install-root/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/addon-build/default/install-root/time.node',
    '/home/ubuntu/development/node_modules/time/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/time.node'
  ]
}
```

Does anyone got these errors before?

node -v: v14.3.0
npm -v: 6.14.5

Comment: The solution provided in [issue #103](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-time/issues/103) may help.

Comment: @RobC that does not help